# Difference between transitive and intransitive verb?

Tags: transitivity

Please tell me if the verbs in the following sentences are transitive or intransitive? please give reason.

caterpillar changes into butterfly.
he got angry with his friends.
they were told to keep quiet.
I am talking with my friend.

secondly, please guide me: Can direct object come after a preposition as well or it has to be right after the verb as one word. 
thanks

Comment: _Tell_ meaning _order_ is a transitive verb (your example is passive). The other verbs are intransitive as they don't have a direct object.

Comment: None of the verbs in your examples are transitive since none of them has a direct object. No: the object of a preposition phrase can't be a direct object. In almost all cases, a direct object immediately follows the verb.